# Displaying the list of data got as snapshot from firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The following is the function to fetch the data from firebase, this contains a list of answers given by the user.

[image: image of how data is stored in firebase]

```
Future<int> getData() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.get();
    final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    print(allData);
    return allData.length;
}
```

The allData is returned in the form below. I an having trouble in displaying the data inside allData in the form of listview.

[image: allData contains image of the form]

Can you please help

Comment: what is the problem here? When asking for help, please explain concisely what you are trying to do and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the data for the first document, you can do:

```
print(allData[0].data);
```

That is an array again, so if you want to then access individual values in there, have a look at [arrays in Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists).